# Sending SMS messages to Email with Android APIs

Tags: android

I have search for a solution and I have not been able to find one.

Is it possible to send a text message (SMS) to and email address?
If so how do you do it with Android APIs?

Comment: sms messages are sent to a phone number, e-mail messages to e-mail address. what is your question?

Comment: Ran, not necessarily true. A phone number has it's own email address (Verizon ex. 0123456789@vtext.com, which you could technically text your phone with through email), and you can send messages to both numbers/email addresses through even the default messaging clients on Android.